# How can I custom horizontal bar on canvas?

Tags: canvas

I have a problem with horizontal bar. I want show the days left to receive a product paid.
I want this:
A horizontal bar with 2 data, one the days total when he will receive the product and other data the actually days completed.
I have this now and it does not work same as I want

```
<div>
 <canvas id="bar-chart-horizontal" width="50px" height="50px"></canvas>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart-horizontal"), {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: {
          labels: ["Days to recive your product"],
          datasets: [
            {
              backgroundColor: ["#ff0000"],
              data: [10]
            }
          ]
        },
        options: {
          legend: { display: false },
        }



   });
</script>
```

I want the bar with 2 datas example 1 days completed of 10 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a sample based on your code.

You should be passing the 2d context to the Chart

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Days to receive your product"],
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: ["red"],
      data: [3]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: true,
        barPercentage: 1,
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          max: 10
        }
      }, {
        display: false,
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" height=80></canvas>
```

Comment: Know how add to the right of the bar a text? Example 4days/10days¿?